# DDD- Mapping events from external Bounded Context to domain model

Tags: domain-driven-design, cqrs, event-sourcing

My team is building a new microservice leveraging techniques from Domain-Driven Design and Event Sourcing. This service has to integrate with a handful of external bounded contexts (BCs) in the form of other legacy services. We've identified our core domain model, and its clear that we need some sort of Anti-corruption layer (ACL) between the external BCs and our internal domain model. However, we're getting hung up on some of the technical details of how best to accomplish this.

Let's say our domain has an **Asset** aggregate which can represent some piece of equipment from several of these external BCs. Once of these BCs, let's say BC-A, sends out **EquipmentUpdate** events on a message broker that our application can subscribe to. These events carry no intent - they merely reflect that the state of the external entity has changed in some way and it's up to us to determine *what* actually changed. The ID in the events is also from the external BC, not our domain.

So our ACL has to do the following tasks:

1. Map the external identifier from BC-A to our internal aggregate
2. Perform a diff of the new event and current/previous state to figure out what actually changed
3. Do this in a way that is resilient against out-of-order and duplicate event messages

#### Option 1 - Query directly from repository

First option is to use the external identifier directly in our repository to fetch the matching **Asset**. This seems like the simplest option, however it feels wrong since it's leaking concepts from external BCs into our repository API.

Furthermore, it forces us to to store external identifiers and event version directly on our aggregate which also feels like it defeats the purpose of the ACL.

```
interface AssetRepository {
    Optional<Asset> findAssetByExternalIdentifier(String externalId);
}
```

#### Option 2 - Dedicated mapping

Second option is to expose a dedicated query that uses the external identifier to query the matching internal identifier, as well as the latest version that was processed.

This feels cleaner, but requires an additional read from the database where option 1 was a single read.

```
data class AssetMappingQueryResult {
    String AssetId;
    Long LatestVersion;
}

interface AssetMappingQuery {
    Optional<AssetMappingQueryResult> resolveFromExternalIdentifier(String externalId);
}
```

How are other teams doing this?

Answer (score 3):

I would tend to treat the `EquipmentUpdate` message as a signal that something might have changed.  On receipt of such a message, the ACL queries BC-A for the latest state for the associated IDs, compares that state with the state it received the last time, and emits commands corresponding to the state changes which are of interest to the bounded context you're developing.  In the case of duplicate messages (where the second event conveys no state change), this approach is idempotent.  The confluence of "select current" likewise makes out-of-order not a concern.  The ACL may want to guard against concurrent modifications involving the same ID, though viewing its output as commands against your BC's write model might make that unnecessary (especially depending on the chance that one of the concurrent modifications might be slow).  The specific techniques for that vary, my personal preference coming from the Akka world would be to have responsibility for a given ID assigned to an actor.

An ACL is by its nature somewhat outside of any bounded context: it's analogous to the space between customs/immigration outposts on the border between countries.  One could say it's partially in both (it's also, from a CQRS standpoint, a read-model for the "other" bounded context, though it may be a "read-model once removed", given that it should probably query a read-model in the source bounded context) bounded contexts.  Alternatively, one could call an ACL a miniature bounded context which incorporates knowledge of parts of two other BCs: this may even extend to having its own aggregates, repositories, etc.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. That all makes sense. The part I'm hung up on is "compares that state with the state it received the last time". These events don't have the primary keys of our BC, so what's the cleanest way to make that association in the ACL?

Comment: It's going to be keyed by other/from-context ID, so part of the ACL's state is going to be that mapping of 1 from-context ID to however many to-context IDs.  As for seeding that, you might have the ACL be responsible for that, or if assignment of IDs in this BC is something else's concern, have a channel for sending commands declaring the association to the ACL (the latter is going well on the way to making this ACL nearly a bounded context in it's own right).

Comment: The universe is often fractal, so are our designs capturing that universe...

Comment: I'm also presuming that the requirement that the new BC's IDs be completely separate from the existing IDs has been arrived at after deliberation and domain exploration and not a requirement that's been "read into" the domain.